# react-native get current Day

Tags: android, date, react-native, get

I'm trying to get the current day/month/year in an Android App in react-native.

This is what i've done:

```
currentDay: new Date(),

...

console.log('Date:'+this.state.currentDay ,);
console.log('Day: '+this.state.currentDay.getDay() , 'Month: ' + this.state.currentDay.getMonth(), 'Year :'+ this.state.currentDay.getYear());
```

And in the console I have:

```
Date:Fri Jun 16 2017 11:27:36 GMT+0000 (GMT)
'Day: 5', 'Month: 5', 'Year :117'
```

As you see, `getDay()`, `getMonth()` and `getYear()` don't return what I want...

Comment: You probably want `.getFullYear()` instead of `.getYear()`

Answer (score 35):

You can use this :

```
var today = new Date();
date=today.getDate() + "/"+ parseInt(today.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ today.getFullYear();
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, it's working well!